# how to style differently two pieces of text in a same input type=text

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to style differently two portions of the text in a same
input type=text, much the same as Google does. When you enter a couple of characters
in the Google search box, they are rendered in normal black font, but they are
followed by a suggested completion rendered in gray font. So, we have two portions
with different font properties in a same input box.

Comment: you can't have multiple colors in single text box.

Answer (score 4):

A text input is uni-coloured - no way around that. An effect like this can be achieved only through Javascript trickery.

Google are definitely working with a `div` element with grey text hovering above or below the text input. The `div` is invisible at first, but when you start typing, it will contain the lookup text. It has the same font size as the text input. The text input will contain the full suggestion, and is coloured black.

I imagine this is not entirely trivial to do in a way that works across browsers... but not at all impossible, either. There may already exist a component or jQuery plugin for this.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't actually do that though does it? At least thats not what it looks like on my computer. The textbox is in normal font, it's the suggested completetion items that are styled. They are probably just renedered in a div or something, not an input.

Comment: Activate the new "Instant search" feature e.g. by switching to the U.S. version of Google

Comment: even at mine textbox is having normal font. FYI: i am using instant search

Comment: @Pekka: ok, I shall investigate. I think the point we are both making though is that it isn't actually the text box which is styled. +1 for your answer anyway, it's a clever idea.

Answer (score 0):

Google uses two text boxes directly on top of each-other. They have different text colour, and the top one has a transparent background. Have a look at it using Firebug to see how it works.